# Symfony 3 expected "Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection" given ... when using OneToMany

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, symfony-3.1

I have a problem with this error:

```
Expected argument of type "AppBundle\Entity\BusVehiclesAmenities", "Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection" given
```

**EDIT 3**

After few comments I applied suggestions and error is gone now (remove ArrayCollection from bus vehicles amenities Entity, removed setting bus vehicles amenities entity from controller and removed ORM Join columns on all mapped entites)

Now I have this error:

```
The association AppBundle\Entity\BusVehiclesAmenities#bus refers to the inverse side field AppBundle\Entity\BusVehicles#busVehiclesAmenities which does not exist.
```

Mapped entities

Bus vehicles:

```
/* @ORM\OneToMany(
     *     targetEntity="BusVehiclesAmenities",
     *     mappedBy="bus",
     *     fetch="EXTRA_LAZY",
     *     orphanRemoval=true,
     *     cascade={"persist"}

     * )
     *
     */

    private $busVehiclesAmenities;
```

bus vehicles amenities entity:

```
private $bus;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Amenities", inversedBy="amenities")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="amenities_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *
     */
```

I am using Collection of Forms to create OneToMany relationship. Problem is when I adding new data I got this error.

Does someone knows where is the problem?

CODE:
Bus Entity (Parent)

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BusVehiclesAmenities", mappedBy="bus", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, fetch="EAGER", orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bus_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     *
     */

private $busVehiclesAmenities;

    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->busVehiclesAmenities = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Add busVehiclesAmenities
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\BusVehiclesAmenities busVehiclesAmenities
     * @return BusVehicles
     */
    public function addBusVehiclesAmenities(BusVehiclesAmenities $busVehiclesAmenities)
    {

         if ($this->busVehiclesAmenities->contains($busVehiclesAmenities)) {
             return;
         }
        $this->busVehiclesAmenities->add($busVehiclesAmenities);
        $busVehiclesAmenities->addBus($this);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set busVehiclesAmenities
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\BusVehiclesAmenities busVehiclesAmenities
     * @return BusVehicles
     */
    public function setBusVehiclesAmenities(BusVehiclesAmenities $busVehiclesAmenities)
    {

         $this->busVehiclesAmenities = $busVehiclesAmenities;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove busVehiclesAmenities
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\BusVehiclesAmenities $busVehiclesAmenities
     * @return BusVehicles
     */
    public function removeBusVehiclesAmenities(BusVehiclesAmenities $busVehiclesAmenities)
    {
        if (!$this->busVehiclesAmenities->contains($busVehiclesAmenities)) {
            return;
        }
        $this->busVehiclesAmenities->removeElement($busVehiclesAmenities);
        $busVehiclesAmenities->removeBus($this);

        return $this;



    }
```

Amenity Entity (Child)

```
/**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BusVehicles", inversedBy="busVehiclesAmenities")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bus_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *
     */
    private $bus;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bus = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * @param BusVehicles $busVehicles
     */

    public function addBus(BusVehicles $busVehicles)
    {
        if ($this->bus->contains($busVehicles)) {
            return;
        }
        $this->bus->add($busVehicles);
        $busVehicles->addBusVehiclesAmenities($this);
    }

    /**
     * @param BusVehicles $busVehicles
     */
    public function removeBus(BusVehicles $busVehicles)
    {
        if (!$this->bus->contains($busVehicles)) {
            return;
        }
        $this->bus->removeElement($busVehicles);
        $busVehicles->removeBusVehiclesAmenities($this);
    }
```

EDIT 1:

I removed ArrayCollection from BusVehiclesAmenitites Entity but I still got same error when I submit form.

EDIT 2:

Added forms

BusVehicles Form Type

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;




class BusVehiclesType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('licencePlate')
            ->add('chassisNumber')
            ->add('manufacturer')
            ->add('busVehiclesAmenities', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type'   => BusVehiclesAmenitiesType::class,
                'prototype' => true,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\BusVehicles',
            'cascade_validation' => true,

        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'adminbundle_busvehicles';
    }


}
```

BusVehiclesAmenities Form Type

```
    <?php

namespace AdminBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use AppBundle\Entity\BusVehiclesAmenities;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;


class BusVehiclesAmenitiesType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('price', NumberType::class, array(

            ))
            ->add('amenities', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' =>'AppBundle:Amenities',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
            ))

        ;

    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => BusVehiclesAmenities::class
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_busvehiclesamenities';
    }


}
```

Controller.

```
/**
     * @Template
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $bus = new BusVehicles();
        $busAmenities = new BusVehiclesAmenities();
        //   $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($busAmenities);
        $bus->setBusVehiclesAmenities($busAmenities);
        $form = $this->createForm(BusVehiclesType::class, $bus);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            /*$form->get('busVehiclesAmenities')->getData()->map(
                function ($amenities) use ($em, $bus) {

                    $bus->setBusVehiclesAmenities($amenities);
                    $em->persist($amenities);
                }
            );*/
            $em->persist($bus);

            $em->flush();

            // Adding flash message to our user

            $this->addFlash('success', 'admin.bus.created');


            //  return $this->redirectToRoute('bus_add');

        }
        return [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run into a similar problem to yours. What I did to fix the situation is remove the JoinColumn. It is actually redundant. It's one of those "magic" things about Symfony which can get annoying IMHO. Just make sure that your OneToMany annotation correctly points back to your ManyToOne. Here's an example-- this is in my User.php Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\UserStats", mappedBy="user")
 */
private $userStats;
```

And this is in the entity being joined (UserStats.php):

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User",
 *     inversedBy="userStats")
 *
 */
private $user;
```

As you can see, there is no JoinColumn, and everything works beautifully as a result. I hope this helps you. :)

Make sure that you use the proper path as I have above, i.e.

```
* (targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="userStats")
```

Comment: thank you for your comment.

I used your suggestion but I am having doctrine mapping error. WIll update my post with new error

Comment: I think the same thing happened to me, and in the end, JoinColumn was not used. Looking forward to seeing your update.

Comment: Okay-- remove this: @ORM\JoinColumn(name="amenities_id", referencedColumnName="id"). There needs to be no JoinColumn in either entity. If you look at my example, I have none in either one, which I pointed out originally. I'll bet this handles it.

Comment: i removed all of them from bus amenitites and error is still there. I still have some left in bus vehicles entity. I will remove all of them and post back result

Comment: I think you are using the wrong format to refer to your entities, i.e. "AppBundle\Entity\User" as in my example. All you are saying is the entity name. I don't think you have the full path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139527/discussion-between-bill-wagner-and-jureispro).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I added exact path of Entites but I still can't map this busVehiclesAmenities in BusVehicles entity class

Answer (score 0):

`BusVehiclesAmenities->bus` is an object, not a collection. The line `$this->bus = new ArrayCollection();` has no reason to exist in your child entity.

You want to achieve ManyToOne, a Many (amentities) aka an `ArrayCollection` in a object (bus) which is a single object.

**Edit**

In your controller you do the following

```
$bus->setBusVehiclesAmenities($busAmenities);
```

This is not needed. The form will handle the collection by himself. *magic*

Your error may come from this call, but this is because you are trying to say `arrayCollection = object` which is not possible.

```
  public function setBusVehiclesAmenities(BusVehiclesAmenities $busVehiclesAmenities)
    {
        // ArrayCollection = Object
        $this->busVehiclesAmenities = $busVehiclesAmenities;
        return $this;
    }
```

You can either try to do `setBusVehiclesAmenities(ArrayCollection $busVehiclesAmenities)` or `Collection`, I don't know, or remove the `setBusVehiclesAmenities` method. (personally I would remove the method)

Also you should check your getter/setter for `bus` in your child, this time your variable is a single object, juste do `getBus()` and `setBus($bus)`, not add and remove.

Hope this may helps you

Comment: thank you for your answer. I removed code but I still have same error when I post form

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. Without" setBusVehiclesAmenities" in controller i form collection of bus amenities is empty.

Answer (score 0):

From Amenity Entity (Child) remove this part of code:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->bus = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

It should solve your problem, if forms have been defined right way.

Explanation - bus in this entity is the owning side of OneToMany relation. It's always one, it can't be a collection.

Comment: So you have to share your forms with us :-)